# c know how much memory was used in the execution

Tags: c, memory

For example, the next code, how to know the memory without the struct timeval and int microseg?.
Is the problem 1 of project Euler.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

int main(){
    struct timeval t, t2;
    struct rusage uso;
    int microseg;
    gettimeofday(&t, NULL);
    int sum = 0;

    for (int k = 2; k < 1000; k++){
        if(k%3 == 0 || k%5 == 0)
            sum +=k;
    }
    printf("%d \n",sum);
    gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);
    microsegundos = ((t2.tv_usec - t.tv_usec)  + ((t2.tv_sec - t.tv_sec) * 1000000.0f));
    printf("CPU time: %d\n",microseg);
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &uso);
    printf("Memory: %ld KB\n", (long)uso.ru_maxrss);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I use https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler for compile.

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. You are already using `ru_maxrss`. Why is that not what you need? "without the struct timeval and int microseg" Those are for time and not memory. So it is not clear why you are mentioning those at all.

Comment: like int microseg; it is using memory, right, so when calling getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &uso) it also takes into account the memory of struct timeval and int microseg, or how getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &uso) actually works?

Comment: Just call the `getrusage` before the code you don't want to include.

Comment: but doesn't getrusage take the maximum memory value from the whole process?

Comment: It does. But it's the max up to the point that the function is called. If the process runs for another 3 days how could the function possibly know today what the maximum memory usage is going to be in 3 days time.